# Наречия с приставкой по-,образованных от сложных прилагательных

Tags: орфография

Увидел новый вопрос Софии "Сколько правил должен знать грамотный человек?'' и вспомнил, что как-то на Грамота.ру поступил вопрос (Вопрос № 267976)
    "Помнится, у Розенталя этот случай оговариался особо:
Примечание 3. В наречиях с приставкой по-, образованных от сложных прилагательных, пишущихся через дефис, последний ставится только после приставки: по-анархосиндикалистски, по-ньюйоркски, по-социалдемократически (ср.: нью-йоркский, социал-демократический).
Зачем вы даете некорректное написание в ответе на вопрос № 267968 "  Ответ справочной службы русского языка: "В таких случаях наречие пишется с двумя дефисами: по-нью-йоркски, по-нью-орлеански..."
Ответ справочной службы русского языка:Академический справочник "Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации" 2006 г. как раз предлагает писать по-социал-демократически и т. д."
Однако, в правилах 1956 г. говорится , что следует писать один дефис( так же во многих других справочниках) . Хотелось бы узнать, знаете ли вы  какие-нибудь другие справочники, где предлагается писать два дефиса?

Вот правило из [полного академического справочника](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=63#pp632.). Наречия с приставкой по-, оканчивающиеся на -ому, -ему, -ски, -цки, -ьи, образованные от прилагательных (в том числе от местоименных прилагательных мой, наш, всякий и т. п.), напр.: по-новому, по-пустому, по-прежнему, по-хорошему, по-вашему, по-твоему, по-своему, по-другому, по-всякому (так же пишется вводное слово по-видимому), по-Петиному (от прилагательного Петин); по-всячески, по-людски, по-дружески, по-русски, по-немецки, по-казацки, по-лисьи, по-собачьи (и просторечные по-ихнему, по-нашенски, по-каковски); наречия по-его, по-её, по-их, образованные от несклоняемых местоименных прилагательных; **по-социал-демократически,** **по-жюлъ-верновски, по-тёти-Валиному.**

Интересно, какой смысл имело вносить поправки в правила 1956 года о дефисном написании наречий ? До 2006 года такое написание не вызывало, насколько мне известно, никаких сомнений. А потом лингвисты, педагоги, филологи( многие из которых работают в РАН), во главе с Лопатином решили почему-то изменить правило.

Comment: Я согласен с мнением В. Лопатина и его коллег о том, что слово "по-национал-социалистически" следует писать с двумя дефисами. Разумность такого правила обоснована Виктором Пановым в его книге "И всё-таки она хорошая ..."

Comment: А не могли бы привести ссылку.Интересно было бы почитать.

Comment: 1. Михаил Викторович Панов "И всё-таки она хорошая! Рассказ о русской орфографии".

2. Мне очень стыдно, что я перепутал имя и отчество Михаила Викторовича.

Comment: К таким словам нужно, наверное, применять особый принцип: букв так много, что без дефиса их не прочитаешь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Два дефиса видеть не приходилось, но вот у меня учебник Гольцова Н. Русский язык 10-11 классы 2007 года, и там есть пример "по-унтерофицерски".

А причина таких колебаний в написании как раз и заключается в отсутствии принципиального решения задачи. Академики в 1956 году сказали, как надо правильно писать, но не объяснили почему.Это должны были сделать другие академики, но не посчитали нужным.

Задача, как мне кажется, должна решаться следующим образом:

1)Определяем значение дефисной формы написания в общем виде. Это промежуточная форма между слитным написанием слова и раздельным написанием словосочетания.

2) У нас есть примеры с двумя дефисами? Есть, но такие слова образованы на основе словосочетаний путем слиянием трех слов: точь-в-точь (точка в точку), не-тронь-меня.

3) В нашем случае мы образуем новое слово из имеющегося материала: две основы, входящие в существительное "унтер-офицер", приставка ПО, суффикс  СКИ.

4) Написание с двумя дефисами искажает настоящее значение слова. Дефисная форма "унтер-офицер" является младшей по сравнению с дефисным написанием приставки ПО и должна как бы понизить свой статус и перейти в слитное написание.

ВЫВОД

Такой  принцип (или другой принцип, но хоть какой-нибудь принцип) желательно сделать общим и применять его ко всем подобным написанием.

Comment: В Интернете есть информация о нем и о его книге. Однако, ни скачать , ни прочитать онлайн эту книгу мне не удалось.Жаль!